# Change x-axis (xlim) on holoviews histogram

Tags: python, holoviews

In matplotlib we can change the limits of the x-axis with the xlim() method. Is there an equivalent method in HoloViews?

I searched the [HV options page](http://ioam.github.io/holoviews/Tutorials/Options), but didn't find anything that seemed to do this.

I created the image below with the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.notebook_extension('bokeh', width=90)

values = np.array([list of floats])

frequencies, edges = np.histogram(values, 10)
hv.Histogram(frequencies, edges)
```

[image: histogram]

How can I change the x-axis limit to [0.002, 0.016].

Also, is it possible to get a plot to return its current x-axis limit?

Comment: I earned the tumbleweed badge for this question. Sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HoloViews will usually just use the bounds of the data you give it. So the easiest way to change the bounds of a histogram is to change it in the np.histogram call itself:

```
frequencies, edges = np.histogram(values, 10, range=(0.002, 0.016))
hv.Histogram(frequencies, edges)
```

If you simply want to change the viewing extents you can do also set those directly:

```
hv.Histogram(frequencies, edges, extents=(0.002, None, 0.016, None))
```

where extents is defined as `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably by adding **.opts(xlim=(0.002, 0.016))** to your plot, like so:

```
hv.Histogram((frequencies, edges)).opts(xlim=(0.002, 0.016))
```

You can do the same for ylim, for example:

```
 .opts(xlim=(0.002, 0.016), ylim=(0, 300))
```

This is all very similar to matplotlib.