# Changing extents or axis limits on complex Holoviews figures

Tags: python, holoviews

I see examples on how to edit the extents (aka axis limits) on single objects like Images or Histograms in holoviews [such as this answer on stack exchange for histogram extents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036534/1361752). What about if you want to apply this to something more complicated like an NdOverlay or HoloMap object? Essentially, I want to apply limits to an entire axis or figure, without worrying about every element I might have in said axis or figure.

For example, suppose I have the following, and want to remove the suppressed zero on the axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6,1,4,9],'C':['a','a','a','b','b','b']})
tbl = hv.Table(df)
fig = tbl.to.curve(kdims=['A'],vdims=['B'],mdims=['C']).overlay()
fig *= hv.Points([(3,4),(5,6),(1,3)])
fig
```

[image: Complex figure]

What is the best way to apply custom plot limits to multi-element objects like this overlay, or to a HoloMap? I'd prefer not to have to filter the data, since this can be cumbersome if you are doing exploratory work combining multiple data-sources. Do I need to apply an extents keyword to each component, or is there an easy way to broadcast it to the whole figure?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to specify explicit axis limits in recent versions of HoloViews is using `xlim` and `ylim` options:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6,1,4,9],'C':
['a','a','a','b','b','b']})
tbl = hv.Table(df)
fig = tbl.to.curve(kdims=['A'],vdims=['B'],mdims=['C']).overlay()
fig *= hv.Points([(3,4),(5,6),(1,3)])
fig.opts(xlim=(0, 6), ylim=(0, 10))
```

Another option (which also works in older versions) is to use the `redim` method (assuming you're using a recent dev release of HoloViews). In your case that would look something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6,1,4,9],'C':
['a','a','a','b','b','b']})
tbl = hv.Table(df)
fig = tbl.to.curve(kdims=['A'],vdims=['B'],mdims=['C']).overlay()
fig *= hv.Points([(3,4),(5,6),(1,3)])
fig.redim(A=dict(range=(0, 6)), B=dict(range=(0, 10)))
```

The `redim` method recursively iterates over your object and lets you override any Dimension parameters including the ranges in this way.

Comment: Note that in the upcoming 1.7 release you'll be able to simplify this further to:

    ``fig.redim.range(A=(0, 6), B=(0, 10))``

Comment: This solution does not work if your axis limits are not natural numbers.

Comment: For categories you can use `.redim.values(category=['A', 'B', 'C'])`